KVM Routed Bridge for Additional Subnet on Hetzner Using Netplan
I have a dedicated Ubuntu 22.04 server at Hetzner running KVM. I have assigned IP addresses from an additional subnet to guest VMs. I can reach the guest VMs via their public IP addresses as intended.
I received an email from Hetzner saying I am using "unallowed" mac addresses and threatening to block the server. The "unallowed" mac addresses belong to the guest VMs. Hetzner support says "You have to make sure that no MAC address of your VMs are going to be visible with the public uplink on your network device." Anyone know how to comply with Hetzner's network rules? Here's my configuration:

PHYSICAL SERVER

$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
    ### Hetzner Online GmbH installimage
    network:
      version: 2
      renderer: networkd
      ethernets:
        enp98s0f0:
          match:
            macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:fa
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
      bridges:
        br0:
          macaddress: xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:fa
          interfaces:
            - enp98s0f0
          dhcp4: no
          dhcp6: no
          addresses:
            - aa.bb.cc.108/32 # Physical NIC (Main IP)
            - aa.bb.cc.65/28 # First usable IP of the additional subnet
          routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: aa.bb.cc.105 # Gateway for Main IP on physical NIC
              on-link: true
            - to: aa.bb.cc.64/28 # Additional subnet
              via: aa.bb.cc.65 # First usable IP of the additional subnet assigned to physical NIC above
              on-link: true
          nameservers:
            addresses:
              - 185.12.64.2
              - 185.12.64.1
          parameters:
            stp: false
            forward-delay: 0


$ cat /etc/sysctl.d/10-forwarding.conf 
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
#net.ipv4.conf.enp98s0f0.send_redirects=0
net.ipv4.conf.all.proxy_arp=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1

$ cat br0.xml
<network>
    <name>br0</name>
    <forward mode='bridge'/>
    <bridge name='br0'/>
</network>


GUEST VM

$ sudo cat /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enp1s0:
      addresses:
      - aa.bb.cc.67/28 # Additional subnet
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 185.12.64.2
        - 185.12.64.1
        search: []
      routes:
      - to: default
        via: aa.bb.cc.65 # First usable IP of the additional subnet assigned to physical NIC
  version: 2


I am unfamiliar with netplan but you need to enable proxyarp, and that is a standard email because else it would explode the arp table with nonsense imho. if it is a total new server I would suggest that you take a look at proxmox

... Proxmox VE will require you to solve this problem too, but various network setups were discussed here and you can find ready answers how to achieve that. Whereas, not many of us use netplan-based system for virtualization in Hetzner.

I solved this with ebtables (layer 2 filtering tool) to ensure all outbound traffic from the guest VMs appears to come from the MAC address of the host's physical NIC. I also disabled Proxy ARP.
sudo apt install ebtables
sudo ebtables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o enp98s0f0 -j snat --to-source xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:fa

The ebtables rule will not survive a reboot. I set up a systemd service to apply them at boot.
Hope this helps someone.

this may not help you anymore as you have a working solution, but another way to solve it is the following:
Use an additional IP (and additional mac for this IP, which Hetzner accepts) as external IP for a router VM and instruct Hetzner via Robot to route your additional network through that additional IP address.
This way only your physical machine's mac and the additional IP's mac are visible to the outside world.
The other VMs are routed through your router VM. This router VM can also protect the VMs on the additional subnet by filtering/firewalling.
